# R cumulative sum based upon other columns

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

I have a data.frame as below. The data is sorted by column txt and then by column val. summ column is sum of value in val colummn and the summ column value from the earlier row provided that the current row and the earlier row have same value in txt column...How could i do this in R?

```
txt=c(rep("a",4),rep("b",5),rep("c",3))
val=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3)
summ=c(1,3,6,10,1,3,6,10,15,1,3,6)
dd=data.frame(txt,val,summ)
> dd
   txt val summ
1    a   1    1
2    a   2    3
3    a   3    6
4    a   4   10
5    b   1    1
6    b   2    3
7    b   3    6
8    b   4   10
9    b   5   15
10   c   1    1
11   c   2    3
12   c   3    6
```

Comment: I do not think that leaving the word "conditional" in the title is helpful. You clearly want a "cumulative" sum. If I'm wrong about that feel free to correct my edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "most earlier" (which in English is more properly written "earliest") you mean the *nearest*, which is what is implied by your expected output, then what you're talking about is a cumulative sum. You can apply [`cumsum()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cumsum.html) separately to each group of `txt` with [`ave()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ave.html):

```
dd <- data.frame(txt=c(rep("a",4),rep("b",5),rep("c",3)), val=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3) );
dd$summ <- ave(dd$val,dd$txt,FUN=cumsum);
dd;
##    txt val summ
## 1    a   1    1
## 2    a   2    3
## 3    a   3    6
## 4    a   4   10
## 5    b   1    1
## 6    b   2    3
## 7    b   3    6
## 8    b   4   10
## 9    b   5   15
## 10   c   1    1
## 11   c   2    3
## 12   c   3    6
```